# XAF CollectionsEditMode

Tags: listview, xaf

When in Application.CollectionsEditMode=Edit mode, nested aggregated child object lists behave as we needed, not saving anything to DB until parent object's save action executes.

But when using Application.CollectionsEditMode=View and setting required DetailView.CollectionsEditMode=Edit from platform's model this behaviour changes and when saving a child, master object is saved too, without waiting any save action execution, and returns to parent object's detail view and switches back to view mode again.

How can we use Application.CollectionsEditMode=View with the same behaviour as Application.CollectionsEditMode=Edit does in required detail views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googled around many times and found this, [devexpress confirmed issue](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T257461)